# 2D dynamically allocated array having access to more memory than allocated size

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I created a 2d array of chars. For each arr[0] I allocate, I allocate one column for it " arr[0][0], arr[1][0],..." However, I have access to more memory than allocated for each column. I have access to arr[0][1],arr[0][2],...
According to understanding, I shouldn't have access to arr[0][1] unless I allocate memory for it.

I included comments representing my understanding of the code

```
char ** sArr = malloc(sizeof(char*)); // create sArr[0]
sArr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char*));   // create sArr[0][0]
sArr[0][0] = 'a';
sArr[0][1] = 'b';
sArr[0][2] = 'c'; 
printf("%c\n", sArr[0][0]);  // outputs 'a' as expected
printf("%c\n", sArr[0][1]);  // outputs 'b', expected error or garbage
printf("%c\n", sArr[0][2]);  // outputs 'c', expected error or garbage
```

I believe I should be able to assign

```
sArr[0][1]='b'
```

only if I used

```
sArr[0] = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: Even if you correctly allocated `sArr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char));` you would likely see `'b'` and `'c'` succeed despite invoking undefined behavior due to the minimum allocation size for `mailloc`. While you may only request `1` byte, `malloc` may allocate more for any number of reasons, from minimum allocation to alignment. The crux isn't what `malloc` actually allocates, it is what you may validly use...

Answer (score 1):

You allocated space for `sizeof(char *)`, a pointer to a character. The size of a pointer is probably four or eight bytes depending on your system. If you instead allocate space for `sizeof(char)` (one byte), and try to access beyond the end of the array you'd be invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (bad idea).

Comment: See my edit - I didn't read your code closely enough the first time.

Comment: Oh my bad. Actually, I changed char* to char, but there's no undefined behavior still and I have access to that unallocated memory

Comment: Well, that’s the thing about undefined behavior— it’s entirely undefined, meaning a program crash is as valid as the program working. My guess is that this program is small enough that you are overwriting free memory, so it still works as expected. However, if this block of code was executed after another block it might clobber data already stored, destroy return values, or otherwise corrupt your memory. You just can’t rely on UB - it’s up to you to manage your memory (including freeing) in a safe way.